# Using defined macro inside csdef

Tags: fontsize, etoolbox

I have defined new font size switches using the following code.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\vi@mult}{2.986}
\newcommand{\HUGE}{\normalsize%
    \@setfontsize\HUGE{\vi@mult\dimexpr\f@size pt\relax}{\vi@mult\dimexpr\f@baselineskip\relax}%
}
\makeatother
```

Is it possible to rewrite this definition such that I can define a new font size switch `\foo` using a macro like the following?

```
\newcommand{\newfontsize}[2]{%
    \csdef{#1}{%
        \normalfont%
        \@setfontsize\csname #1\endcsname{#2\dimexpr\f@size pt\relax}{#2\dimexpr\f@baselineskip\relax}%  This line produces an error.
    }%
}
\newfontsize{foo}{3.583}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure why you'd want `\newfontsize{foo}{...}` instead of `\newfontsize{\foo}{...}`, since you're defining a command, aren't you?

Comment: @egreg You're right. I realize only now that you can pass a yet-undefined macro and define it inside the replacement string. I hyperfocused on `\csname` and `\expandafter` for some reason. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\@setfontsize` defined in `latex.ltx` takes three non-separated parameters. In your first example it is:

```
\@setfontsize\HUGE{\vi@mult\dimexpr\f@size pt\relax}{\vi@mult\dimexpr\f@baselineskip\relax}
```

first parameter is `\HUGE`, second `\vi@mult\dimexpr\f@size pt\relax` and third is `vi@mult\dimexpr\f@baselineskip\relax`. But in you second example

```
\@setfontsize\csname foo\endcsname{#2\dimexpr\f@size pt\relax}{#2\dimexpr\f@baselineskip\relax}
```

the first parameter in `\csname`, second `f` and third `o`. This isn't what you want. Use `\expandafter`:

```
\expandafter\@setfontsize\csname foo\endcsname{#2\dimexpr\f@size pt\relax}{#2\dimexpr\f@baselineskip\relax}
```

The `\expanafter` runs `\csname foo\endcsname` and creates `\foo`. Then `\@setfontsize` has parameters: `\foo`, `3.583\dimexpr\f@size pt\relax` and `3.583\dimexpr\f@baselineskip\relax`. Maybe, this is what you want.